# NaN returned from this code

Tags: javascript, random, runtime-error, nan

This code will not print our the roomC instead it returns nan I have traced back through the code and determined that the code

```
var minR = (Game.height * Game.width) / 300;
var maxR = (Game.height * Game.width) /150;
```

causes nan to occur here is the entirety of the code any help would be appreciated!

```
Game = {


mapG:{
    width: 75,
    height: 50,
    tile:{
        width: 10,
        height: 10
    }
},


width: function() {
 return this.mapG.width * this.mapG.tile.width;
},


height: function() {
  return this.mapG.height * this.mapG.tile.height;
},

start: function() {

var minR = (Game.height * Game.width) / 300;
var maxR = (Game.height * Game.width) /150;
var range = maxR - minR + 1;
var roomC = Math.floor((Math.random()*maxR)+minR);

//#3L11Tw0w0w0w0
Crafty.init(Game.width(), Game.height());
Crafty.background('rgb(6, 38, 111)');

var map =[];
for(var x = 0; x < 100; x++){
    map[x] = [];
    for(var y = 0; y < 100; y++){
       map[x][y] = x*y;
   }


  }



console.log(map[10][11]);
    //Need this to print out!
console.log(roomC);
}

}
```

Comment: Try changing `Game` in those two lines to `this`.

Comment: @PitaJ Doesn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is when you are calling the function width and height. you need to call them like that:

```
var minR = (Game.height() * Game.width()) / 300;
var maxR = (Game.height() * Game.width()) /150;
```

I think this should solve the problem.

Comment: I definitely think this is the problem

Comment: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pitaj/tLExC/4/ it won't load on Chrome, just use dev tools